# blackberry deployment and release process

Tags: deployment, blackberry, release

So I'm building a blackberry app and was wondering if there is any good documentation on deployment/release best practices? Blackberry's "A70 – How to Deploy and Distribute Applications" document is kind of lacking.

I guess I'm looking for answers for the following question (Specifically for Over-The-Air aka OTA):

1. I'm building an app for OS 4.5 and up. Do I need to compile a separate COD/JAD for each version? (i.e. 4.5, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.7, and 5.0)
2. How do I detect OS version from the user-agent?
3. What's the best way to compile COD/JAD files?
4. anything else that might be good to know :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No you don't need to compile a separate cod file for each version although my understanding is that OS 5 will run older applications in a compatibility mode which can mess things up so you may want to compile separately for that if there are any problems.
2. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_user_agents_for_mobile_phones#BlackBerry) the user agent seems to follow the format "BlackBerry / Profile/..."
3. I'm really not sure what you're looking for here.  As far as I know the rapc compiler doesn't have any optimization abilities so however you compile it it's going to produce the same result.

Comment: for number 3, How do you generate the cod/jad files? I typically run the simulator which ends up creating the necessary files for me. Is this how other developers do it?

Comment: If it's not set to build automatically and I'm going to just test something on the device without running it through the simulator first then I'll press Alt-B to build it.  There's also a BlackBerry ant plugin (http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/main) if you'd prefer to use that.

Comment: @hishboy if you right-click the project, there is a BlackBerry menu, which allows you to package the project. This is better than using the "simulator" files as you suggested.